# Microsoft Access Lost Back-end File Size

Tags: ms-access

I have the problem with MS. Access. The problem is, My current MS. Access Back-end file size is 320 MB but after I compact database it still has file size only 222 MB so it mean I lost file size 98 MB. My question is, what that problem? after it lost file size 98 MB why it keep more slower then before when user use it? What about record in that file lost or not? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you delete data from a table it is not deleted from the db, just marked as deleted. It gets deleted on Cpmpact (that should be done regular, if large amount of data is deleted). Usually the db speeds up after that. Why yours slows down should have other reasons. If you want a reliable backend use something like `SQL-Server` etc.

Comment: _Compact_ means just that. It compacts the file to the size of its net content, removing remains from temp tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour, and you did not lose any data. A compact + repair (C + R) is a normal maintains that you should do on your database. How often you do this kind off maintains will much depend on how many users, how much data “churning” etc.

So some can go for weeks, or even perhaps longer without having to C + R the back end. Some, much less time.

So why does the file grow like this?

There are several reasons, but one is simply that to allow multiple users, then when you delete a record, access cannot reclaim the disk space, because you (may) have multiple users working with the data. You cannot “move” all that other data down to fill the “hole” because that would CHANGE the position of existing data.

So if I am editing record 400, and another user deletes record 200, then a “hole” exists at 200. However, if I want to reclaim the space, I would have to “move down” every single record to fill that hole. So if the database has 100,000 records, and I delete record 50, then I now have to move a MASSIVE 99950 records back down to fill that one hole! That is way too slow.

So in place of the HUGE (and slow) process of processing 99950 records (a lot of data) then access just simple leaves the “hole” in that spot.

The reason is multi-user. With say 5 users working on the system, then you can’t start moving around data WHILE users are working. The place or spot of an existing record would thus be moving all the time.

So moving records around is NOT practical if you are to allow multiple users.

The other issue that causes file growth is that if you open up and edit record (again say position and record 50 out of 100,000). What happens if you type in extra information and now the record is TOO LARGE for that spot at position 50?

So now your record is too large. Now we have the opposite problem of a delete – we need to expand and make the “hole” or spot 50 larger. And to do that, we might have to move 100,000 or more records to increase the size of the hole for that one record.

The “hole” or “spot” for the record is NOT large enough anymore.

So what access does is simply mark and set the old record (the old spot) as deleted, and then access puts the too large record we just editing at the end of the file (thus expands at the end of the file). So the file grows, even with just editing, and not necessary only due to delets.

So deleting a record does not really “remove” the hole, and is to slow from a performance point of view.

And as noted, if we move records (which is way too slow), then other users working on the data would find the position of the current record they are working on NOT in the same place anymore.

So we can’t start “moving around” that data during edting.

So access is NOT able to re-claim space during operation. It is too slow, causes way too much disk i/o for a simple delete, and also as noted would not work in multi-user when position of records are always changing due to some delete.

To reclaim all those “holes” and “spots”, then you do a C + R. So this is a scheduled type of maintains that you do when no one is working on data. (say late at night, or after all workers go home). This also explains why only ONE user can be working to do a C + R.

So you not losing any data – the C + R simply is re-claiming all those “holes” and “spots” of un-used space, but the process is time consuming.

So it is too slow “during” operation of your application to re-claim those spots. Such re-claim of wasted and un-used space thus only occurs during a C + R, and not during high speed and interactive operations when your users are working.

I should point out that “most” database systems have this issue, and while “some” attempt re-claim the un-used space, it is simple better to have a separate process and separate action to reclaim that space during system maintains, not during use of the application.

What you are seeing is normal.

And after a C + R you should see improved performance. Often not much, but if the file is really large, full of lots of gaps and holes, then a C + R will reduce the file size a lot, and can help perfoamnce. Access also re-builds the indexes, and also orders data by PK order – this can also increase performance as you “more often” get to read data in PK order.